# $\gcd(a, 63) = 1$ implies $a^7 \equiv a \mod 63$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $a$ be an integer. Suppose that $\gcd(a,63) = 1$. Prove then that $$a^7 \equiv a \mod 63. $$

**Attempt:** Since $gcd(a,63) = 1$, by Fermat little theorem we have that $$a^{\phi(63)} \equiv 1 \mod 63. $$ Now I found a prime factorization of $63$. We have $63 = 3^2 \cdot 7$. Hence $$\phi(63) = (3-1)3 \cdot 6 = 36. $$ So I got $$a^{36} \equiv 1 \mod 63. $$ Now I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: look $\mod 3^2$ and $\mod 7$ separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note. $(a,63)=1 \implies (a,7)=1$. And by [FLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) you have $$a^{6} \equiv 1 \pmod{7} \implies a^{7}\equiv a \pmod{7}$$ And since $(a,9)=1 \implies a^{\phi(9)}=a^{6} \equiv 1 \pmod{9} \implies a^{7}\equiv a \pmod{9}$. Now use [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).